# How to design a database for nested types

Tags: sql, laravel, database-design

[image]

So I have main table service , each service should have type and might have sub type, the provider will add price to either type or sub type (if parent type have it) , now I want to add another sub sub type with many-to-many relation with the SubType table and I want the provider to be able to add price for it (if parent type have it) .

1. Example : I have service name clean home and this service have type of meter, with no sub type the provider will add the price only for the type.
2. Second ex: I have service name clean sofa and this service have type of sofa and the type of sofa have sub types like big sofa, small sofa.
3. Third ex: I have service clean car and this service has type of car and the type of car have sub types like small car , big car, now those sub types have also sub type like inside clean or outside clean, so now the provider should add price to each sub sub types.